# CompareTo Function Issue

Tags: java, compareto

Help I cant figure out the compareTo Function. This is what I have to do: Write a compareTo function that can be used to place the products in order according 
to their part numbers.  That is, a part number that is later in alphabetical 
order is greater than a part number that is earlier in alphabetical order.
This is my code:

```
public class ProductType implements Comparable<ProductType> {
    private String partnum;
    private double price;
    private int stock;

    public ProductType(String partnum, double price, int stock) {
        this.partnum = partnum;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public ProductType() {
        partnum = "";
        price = 0;
        stock = 0;
    }

    public void setNum(String partnum) {
        this.partnum = partnum;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getNum() {
        return partnum;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public int compareTo(ProductType otherType) throws NullPointerExeption {
        if (otherType == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        return (this.getNum().compareTo.otherType.getNum());
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "" + this.getNum();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just seem to have a dot rather than a bracket. It should be `this.getNum().compareTo(otherType.getNum())`

Comment: @pbabcdefp can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @SezinKarli I made it a comment as I wasn't sure if that was the only problem. It's appeared as an answer now anyway.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why did you thought, that you can use `compareTo` like this? Have you thought that this is a field, instead of a method?

Answer (score 4):

change your return statement

```
 return (this.getNum().compareTo.otherType.getNum());
```

to

```
 return (this.getNum().compareTo(otherType.getNum()));
```

because `compareTo()`  is method.

before calling `compareTo()` method check whether

```
null != this.getNum()
```

otherwise you will get NPE.

Comment: I'm still getting an error for the NullPointerException

Comment: @Dem check (this.getNum() != null) before comparing.